# Statistically, what is the best place in the United States to restart civilization?

Tags: post-apocalypse, civilization

so for background :

- the world is post apocalyptic.
- a handwavium virae kill most of humanity.
- with the government is collecting is remaining population to a good area,we assume there is only 100.000 humans left on earth.
- we assume that the land is safe and isn't toxicated.
- we assume they have a mean for doing so.
- this taking place in the us.

my question :
which state, or part of a state, or a county, with a good enough resources and good farmland to start over the civilization ?

Comment: Q: What's the US population ? do you mean 100.000 humans on the planet ? How many in America ?

Comment: yes i mean around 100k human left on earth.

Comment: how long after the apocalypse, stuff the like the hoover dam could keep generating power for a good long while.

Comment: Maine. Close to a civilized country, Canada, and almost devoid of extremist views. No built-up areas that will be impossible to maintain, predominantly rural infrastructure that does not depend on  modern technology or require tremendous sources of electricity or refined resources, none of which will be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pennsylvania

- Plenty of hydropower for your water wheels (since 100,000 is too few to support an electrical infrastructure and supporting industry)
- Plenty of temperate farmland...and grazing land for the beasts of burden your population will need.
- Oil for your single tiny refinery.
- Large woodlands capable of sustainably supporting the 18th century energy needs of your population.
- Many counties with current populations around 100,000, lots of  appropriately-sized towns, infrastructure, and facilities. Much housing stock in many towns pre-date electrification, so can be fairly easily retrofitted back to the new 18th-century wood-burning lifestyle.
- Dense roadway and railway networks, providing alternate routes as the pavements and bridges decay and fail, and room for growth when you re-invent steam engines. Also, short distances between woodland, farmland, and towns (originally settled by horse-drawn wagons).
- Plenty of iron and steel and machines and other resources in nearby cities for convenient recycling.
- Generally mild temperatures in winters and summers.

Comment: Also coal, salt, limestone, copper, and iron mines and right next to jersey which has the super rare nickel mines.

Answer (score 2):

### Minnesota

- lots of good farmland
- far enough North that summer heat is not debilitating
- lots of freshwater lakes + winter snow = potable water
- origin of the Mississippi river, good for transport
- borders a Great Lake
- plenty of modern infrastructure, including one of the world's best hospitals
- home of [SPAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)), so there will be a huge supply of shelf-stable, high-calorie food on abandoned grocery shelves and in factories
- floods & tornadoes are the only natural disasters in MN (i.e. no earthquakes, volcanoes, tsunamis, etc); *not* part of [Tornado alley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_Alley)

Comment: And if you are in the forests, you avoid the 50-mph wind at 20 below that happens out in the open prairie.

Answer (score 2):

**Beaver Island, Lake Michigan**

America's Emerald Isle. When the world's population will remain similar and 4.5% of 100.000 survivors on Earth are American, there will be some 4,500 Americans.

For convenience and hospitality: some 40 folks on the island happened to survive the pandemia. Instead of tourists, 4,500 evacuees will arrive.

- Forest
- Clean air
- Wind power
- Friendly folks
- Tranquility
- Rehab center
- Agriculture
- Plenty of fish

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver_Island_(Lake_Michigan)

[image]

Comment: Rehab center? That IS tempting!

Comment: Definitely not a joke: after probably *years* of lock down restrictions.. lots of people arriving will have an issue.. a small community will allow them to heal and the island is famous for their clinic.